# AzureSQL: What is the automation/script name for PremiumRS service tiers?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

In AzureSQL, what is the name for PremiumRS service tiers?
My automation script upsizes my database from Standard S3 to Premium P1 each morning at 6am but I wish to change this to upsize to PremiumRS PS1.

This is the script I'm using:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f

Comment: It appears as if the new PremiumRS tiers are not able to be automated yet.  The webhook doesn't work and last night I had a database set to PRS2 and the automation script for that database, that has run flawlessly for months, failed to drop it to S0. I assume, because it was a PRS tier.

Comment: Error reported from the automation script last night:
`Set-AzureSqlDatabase : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Database'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value 
for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At AzureSQLScaling:71 char:71
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-AzureSqlDatabase], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Database.Cmdlet.SetAzureSqlDatabase
`

Answer (score 0):

Service tiers are PRS1, PRS2, PRS4 and PRS6. I would also recommend to you double checking availability regions.

For service tiers:
http://blog.nilayparikh.com/azure/sql/update-microsoft-azure-sql-database-increase-storage-up-to-4tb/

For regions:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sql-database-4tb-premium-and-premium-rs-preview/

Comment: Thank you but what is the category name? ie: Standard, Premium, Basic... I would assume it's PremiumRS but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See the Create Database (Azure SQL Database) topic at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268335.aspx for the syntax for create. 
Similarly, see the Alter Database (Azure SQL Database) topic at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt574871.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I used premiumrs and PRS4 in a webhook but it's not working. -- Works just fine if I use premium and P2

Comment: The category would be 'Premium RS'. Try again including whitespace.